# Box counting dimension of line segment [0,1]?

Tags: fractals, fractal-analysis

I am not understanding this example from Kenneth Falconers book on Fractal geometry. 
[image]

can someone please explain how the inequalities follows from the definitions in the example given?

Comment: Bump? I have edited the question now.

Comment: Observe, $N=N_{\delta}(F)$ always exists. Note that $N\geq 2$. Since $0<\delta<1$, it follows that $N\delta\geq 1$. Hence $N\geq \frac{1}{\delta}$.